# Dateinput function not functioning in filter

Tags: r

Below is my UI function in Flexdashboard. But when I try to on dates range, I am not getting the out. Below is the sample dataframe

```
df 
Date                              Variable      
21-09-2017  22:05:00               A         
22-09-2017  22:05:00               B
23-09-2017  22:05:00               C
24-09-2017  22:05:00               D
24-09-2017  22:05:00               E
```

Filter function function below.(Not sure what wrong I am doing here in Filter function. I need both Variable and Date in filters

```
output$g1 <- renderPlotly({
    req(input$Plot1)
    if (input$Plot1 == "Trend") {
        plot_data <- df
    }
    if (input$Plot1 == "Trend" & input$b != "All" & input$s2 != NULL) {
        #plot_data <- df %>% filter(variable == input$b)
        plot_data <- df[df$variable %in% input$b & df$Date %in% input$s2,]
    }
```

UI function below

```
    selectInput("Plot1","Filter1",choices = c("","Trend","Correlation"))
    output$filter_2 <- renderUI({
    if (input$Plot1 == "") {
    return()
    } else if (input$Plot1 == "Trend") {
      label = "Trend"
      selectInput("b",label,choices = c("All",levels(factor(df$variable))),multiple = TRUE)
    } else {
      label = "First Variable"
      selectInput("b",
                label,
                choices = c(levels(factor(df$variable))))
    }
    })
uiOutput("filter_2")
uiOutput("filter_4")
     output$filter_4 <- renderUI({
       if(input$Plot1 == "Trend"){
         dateRangeInput("s2","Date",min = min(df$Date),max = max(df$Date))
       } else if(input$Plot1 == "Correlation"){
         dateRangeInput("s2","Date",min = min(df$Date),max = max(df$Date))
       }
     })
```

Comment: `input$s2 != NULL`  can be `!is.null(input$s2)`

Comment: Almost working but I am concerned with ````plot_data <- df[df$variable %in% input$b & df$Date %in% input$s2,]````. This filtering is not working when I filter in Dates

Comment: If it is `Date` variable, I guess 'Date' is `Date` class and 's2' 'character' right.  Change both to a single type with `as.Date`

Comment: Oh. But do I convert s2, it is not a variable here right?

Comment: I assume `input$s2` as "2019-04-01" value instead of a variable name

Comment: Yes it is ````dateRangeInput("s2","Date",min = min(df$Date),max = max(df$Date))````. We cant gives choices to dateRangeinput

Comment: So, you are getting a sequence of dates from 'min' to 'max', right?  But, my question is whether the class of `input$s2` is `character` or not.  You can check by using a single filter for Dates and see if it works

Comment: I find your 'Date' with time as well and not in the DateTime (POSIXct format) `21-09-2017  22:05:00`  Have you changed the class before taking the `min` and `max`

Comment: Nope I need in POSIXct format only. Because I am seeing a trend here. I also need minutes and hours. Yes, I checked for single filter for date, it is not working

Comment: then you need to first convert the 'Date' to `as.POSIXct(Data, format = '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')`

Comment: @akrun it is in "POSIXct" "POSIXt" format only after converting .

Comment: That is correct.  Now, you take the `min/max` and use that in `daterange` and also wrap `as.POSIXct(input$s2)`

Comment: you mean here ````plot_data <- df[df$variable %in% input$b & df$Date %in% as.POSIXct(input$s2),]```` ?

Comment: Yes, I would expect it to work

Comment: Error  : do not know how to convert '.' to class"POSIXct"

Comment: You have `req(input$Plot1)`  try similar for `req(input$s2)`

Comment: Because I used ````df %>% as.POSIXct(df, format = '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')```` to convert because if I directly convert, as soon as I open the app, the screen is filled with dates only :) May be because of this?

Comment: Your code is converting the whole dataseet to `POSIXct`?  I would expect `df %>% mutate(Date  = as.POSIXct(Date,..`

Comment: Dude the logic is working. But I am sure the filter is not taking hours, minute and seconds into consideration because, The trend line is linear which I am sure it is not. Actually what is happening is that, %d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S is not working and only %d-%m-%Y is working. Hope you got my point

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear because I can't reproduce the  issue.  Also, if it not taking hours, minute, seconds into consideration, it must be stripping that info